# Excel Dependent Drop Down List IF Statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel i have a dependent drop down list that i want to use an if statement in, however i am getting a formula error when adding it to the data validation.

**Formula**

```
=IF( B8 ="Alpha", ='Base Information'!$BF$14:$BF$41, IF( B8="Beta", ='Base Information'!$BF$2:$BF$4, ='Base Information'!$BD$1 ))
```

It looks at Cell B8 and if it contains Alpha the lookup for the drop down list is BF14 to BF41, if B8 is Beta the lookup for the drop down list is BF2 to BF4 else the lookup for the drop down list is BD1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many = Signs.

```
=IF( B8 ="Alpha", 'Base Information'!$BF$14:$BF$41, IF( B8="Beta", 'Base Information'!$BF$2:$BF$4, 'Base Information'!$BD$1 ))
```